# check $.get response and redirect user to URL,but the page keeps reloading

Tags: jquery, laravel

When my page is redirected to another URL, its reloading again and again. I also tried `e.preventdefault();`, `on.load();`

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {             
  if (response.country && response.country == 'IN') {           
    window.location.replace('http://v2.coworkingops.com/in');
    $('#ip-detect').val(response.country);
  }
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: Are you putting this code on every page?

Comment: no it is only on .js page

Comment: But that is included on the page you are redirecting to?

Comment: thak you so much sir

Comment: What the actual fuc* to the comments above. "no it is only on .js page". "I'm trying to help. did you do x?" "thank you so much sir"